# jQuery Slider^2

Tags: jquery, slider

I have tired out **jQuery Slider^2** available at http://wex.im/.

I have made all the (very basic) descriptions that were given but I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'height' of null
```

What did I do wrong? Do you know any alternative for this jq plug-in? Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formatting is wrong. I'll provide the plugin's example code, which you can modify, but I can't find any documentation on this one.

```
<div id="slider" class="jquery-slider" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; ">
                    <div class="simple jquery-slider-element" style="background-image: url(http://wex.im/img/img1.jpg); display: block; left: -600px; ">
                        <h2>Simple</h2>
                        <q>Tested with humen, no monkeys.</q>
                        <a href="get/stable">Download<br>stable</a>
                        <a href="get/devel">Download<br>devel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="light jquery-slider-element" style="background-image: url(http://wex.im/img/img2.jpg); display: block; left: -600px; ">
                        <h2>Light</h2>
                        <q>I think ~5,5k as raw is not too bad.</q>
                        <a href="get/stable">Download<br>stable</a>
                        <a href="get/devel">Download<br>devel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="easy jquery-slider-element" style="background-image: url(http://wex.im/img/img3.jpg); left: 0px; display: block; ">
                        <h2>Easy</h2>
                        <q>$('#slider').slider(); Too hard?</q>
                        <a href="get/stable">Download<br>stable</a>
                        <a href="get/devel">Download<br>devel</a>
                    </div>
                <span class="jquery-slider-pages"><span class="jquery-slider-page jquery-slider-page-current"></span><span class="jquery-slider-page"></span><span class="jquery-slider-page"></span></span><span class="jquery-slider-control jquery-slider-control-prev">«</span><span class="jquery-slider-control jquery-slider-control-next">»</span></div>
```

EDIT:

copy all the code but only modify the "simple jquery-slider-element" style attributes and content (e.g. the h2, a, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var slider1Options = {
                                $Idle: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                                $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                                $CaptionTransitions: captionTransitions_childSliders,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                            },

                            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $SpacingX: 10,                                  //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                                $SpacingY: 10                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                            },

                            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                            }
                        };

                        var jssorSlider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", slider1Options);

                        var slider2Options = {
                            $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                            $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,             //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                            },

                            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                                $CaptionTransitions: captionTransitions_childSliders,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                            },

                            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $SpacingX: 10,                                  //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                                $SpacingY: 10                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                            },

                            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                            }
                        };

                        var jssorSlider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", slider2Options);

                        var bannerSlider_slideshowTransitions = [
                        //Fade in R
                        {$Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
                        //Fade out L
                        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
                        ];

                        var slider3Options = {
                            $Idle: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                                $Transitions: bannerSlider_slideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                            },

                            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $SpacingX: 10,                                  //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                                $SpacingY: 10                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                            },

                            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                            },

                            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $ActionMode: 0,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                                $NoDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
                            }
                        };

                        var jssorSlider3 = new $JssorSlider$("slider3_container", slider3Options);

                        function IsBrowserIe8Earlier() {
                            var isBrowserIe8Earlier;

                            var app = navigator.appName;
                            var ua = navigator.userAgent;

                            if (app == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" &&
                            !!window.attachEvent && !!window.ActiveXObject) {

                                var ieOffset = ua.indexOf("MSIE");

                                browserRuntimeVersion = document.documentMode || parseFloat(ua.substring(ieOffset + 5, ua.indexOf(";", ieOffset)));

                                isBrowserIe8Earlier = browserRuntimeVersion < 8;
                            }
                        }

                        var sliderClusterSlideshowOptions = IsBrowserIe8Earlier() ? null : {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                            $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                            $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                            $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                        };

                        var slidercOptions = {
                            $AutoPlay: false,                                   //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                            $AutoPlayInterval: 3000000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
                            $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                            $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                            $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                            $SlideshowOptions: sliderClusterSlideshowOptions,

                            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                                $CaptionTransitions: captionTransitions,        //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                            },

                            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $AutoCenter: 2                                  //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                            },

                            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                                $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                                $SpacingY: 4                                    //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                            }
                        };

                        var jssorSliderc = new $JssorSlider$("sliderc_container", slidercOptions);

                        //responsive code begin
                        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
                        function ScaleSlider() {
                            var parentWidth = jssorSliderc.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                            if (parentWidth)
                                jssorSliderc.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 960), 300));
                            else
                                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                        }
                        ScaleSlider();

                        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
                        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
                        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                        //responsive code end

                        //slider cluster controller code begin
                        function SliderCluster(mainSlider, autoPlayInterval) {
                            var _Self = this;
                            var _NestedSliders = [];
                            var _NestedSliderCurrent;

                            var _CaptionInCounter = 0;

                            function OnChildSliderStateChange(currentIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd) {
                                if (progress == idleBegin) {
                                    if (!(++_CaptionInCounter % 4)) {

                                      //  _NestedSliderCurrent && _NestedSliderCurrent.$Pause();

                                        mainSlider.$Play(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            function OnMainSliderStateChange(currentIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd) {

                                _NestedSliderCurrent = _NestedSliders[currentIndex];

                                if (_NestedSliderCurrent) {
                                    if (progress == idleBegin) {

                                        mainSlider.$Pause();
                                        _NestedSliderCurrent.$Play(true);
                                    }
                                    else if (progress == progressBegin) {
                                        _CaptionInCounter = 0;
                                        mainSlider.$Play(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            function OnMainSliderSwipeStart(position, virtualPosition) {
                                _NestedSliderCurrent && _NestedSliderCurrent.$Pause();
                                mainSlider.$Pause();
                            }

                            function OnMainSliderPark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
                                _CaptionInCounter = 0;
                                mainSlider.$Play();
                            }

                            _Self.$AddChildSlider = function (childSlider, slideIndex) {
                                _NestedSliders[slideIndex] = childSlider;
                                childSlider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, OnChildSliderStateChange);
                            };

                            _Self.$Start = function () {
                                mainSlider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnMainSliderPark);
                                mainSlider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, OnMainSliderStateChange);
                                mainSlider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SWIPE_START, OnMainSliderSwipeStart);

                                mainSlider.$Play(true);
                            }
                        }

                        var sliderCluster = new SliderCluster(jssorSliderc);
                        sliderCluster.$AddChildSlider(jssorSlider1, 0);
                        sliderCluster.$AddChildSlider(jssorSlider2, 1);
                        //sliderCluster.$AddChildSlider(jssorSlider3, 2);
                        sliderCluster.$Start();

                        //slider cluster controller code end
                    });
```